# How can I add ruby code values to disqus javascript variables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, disqus

Here's the default disqus code:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
        var disqus_shortname = 'mysite'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
```

...

I want to add a disqus_identifier based on the id of the object whose page is showing.  I tried the following 2 solutions with no luck.

```
var disqus_identifier = "<%=mysite_#{@illustration.id}%>"; 

var disqus_identifier = "mysite_<%=#{@illustration.id}%>";
```

How do you interpolated a ruby value in to a js variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close with your second example.  You'll want to structure it like this:

```
var disqus_identifier = "mysite_<%= @illustration.id %>";
```